# Regex list of specific emails in an input expression

Tags: regex, html

I am currently using this regex pattern in my input form, which works perfectly.

```
<input type='text' name='email' autocomplete="off" id='email' required pattern="[a-z0-9._%+-]+@example+\.[a-z]{2,3}$" value='<?php echo $fgmembersite->SafeDisplay('email') ?>' maxlength="50" /><br/>
```

But now I want to insert a list of specific e-mail addresses, like blab1111@example.com, blab1211@example.com etc pp.

Is there a possibility to change the `[a-z0-9._%+-]` into a list of `[\bblab1111\b \bblab1211\b]`?

currently active snipped, without the list:

```css
 input:invalid {
  background: hsla(0, 90%, 70%, 1);
}

input:valid {
  background: hsla(100, 90%, 70%, 1);
}
```

```html
<input type='text' name='email' autocomplete="off" id='email' required pattern="[a-z0-9._%+-]+@example+\.[a-z]{3}$" maxlength="50" /><br/>
```

Comment: Search about "groups" *(capturing or non-capturing)* in a regex tutorial.

Comment: I guess you just need to replace `[a-z0-9._%+-]+` with `(blab1111|another_bla)`, and add as many `|`-separated alternatives as you need to the `(...)` group ([fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/soeb7kqm/)).

Comment: Are you sure the check you want to perform must be done on client side?

Comment: Yes. They are only allowed to enter and submit a registrationform with a specific type of email (in this case the email of an institute), with the from the institute hosted email address. So that everybody else, who don't owns one of those email addresses allowed in the pattern, can't even registrate/ submit the form.

Comment: It's a naive belief, if you do that on client side (in an html attribute), absolutely everyone can see all the email addresses by simply displaying the source code of the page. This must be done on server side. You must peform this test with PHP, when the form is submitted.

Comment: The thing is, if you don't own this email address, you don't get the confirmation email. So it doesn't matter, if you see the mail addresses or not. It's not the only safety method we are using, just a small shenanigan.

Comment: A more proper way, if you want something more 'interactive' consists to perform an ajax call to a php script when the email field looses the focus.

Comment: Okay, I will check that out! Thank you. :)

Comment: Other problem if you make emails visible to everyone, these emails addresses may become the target of spam attacks.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, thanks to [Wiktor Stribiżew](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3832970/wiktor-stribi%C5%BCew) (answerd in the comments).

This works:

```css
 input:invalid {
  background: hsla(0, 90%, 70%, 1);
}

input:valid {
  background: hsla(100, 90%, 70%, 1);
}
```

```html
<input type='text' name='email' autocomplete="off" id='email' required pattern="(blab1111|blab1211)+@example+\.[a-z]{3}$" maxlength="50" /><br/>
```